# How to do inheritance

Tags: arduino

can't understand how to properly inherit objects. There is my code:

```
#include <ArduinoSTL.h>

class Element {
public:
    Element() {

    };
    virtual void execute() {
        Serial.print("element\n");
    }
};
class ExtendedElement : public Element {
public:
    ExtendedElement() : Element() {

    }
    virtual void execute() {
        Serial.print("extended element\n");
    }
};
class Wrapper {
private:
    std::vector<Element> elements;

public:
    void execute() {
        for (Element element : elements) {
            element.execute();
        }
    }

    void addTask(Element element) {
        elements.push_back(element);
    }
};

Wrapper wrapper;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    ExtendedElement extendedElement = new ExtendedElement();
    wrapper.addTask(extendedElement);
}

void loop() {
    wrapper.execute();
}
```

So, I want to extend class, create an instance of this extended class, and put such instance into vector of base class.
Then I want to iterate over elements in vector, and call child class function. Can't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: When there is something wrong, you have to describe what is wrong? Is there a compiler error? If yes, show it in your question (copy and paste it there). Does the code behave wrong? Then describe, what behavior you have expected and what behavior you are seeing.

Comment: Vector of `Element` can only store objects of `Element` class. `ExtendedElement extendedElement = new ExtendedElement();` is also not valid, because right part produces a pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

result of `new` should be assigned to a pointer

```
ExtendedElement *extendedElement = new ExtendedElement();
```

elements should be a vector of pointers

```
class Wrapper {
private:
    std::vector<Element*> elements;

public:
    void execute() {
        for (Element *element : elements) {
            element->execute();
        }
    }

    void addTask(Element *element) {
        elements.push_back(element);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You have discovered what's called *object slicing*. Your vector stores `Element` objects not `ExtendedElement` objects. When you add an `ExtendedElement` object to your vector it is converted to an `Element` (this is the slicing part) so your `ExtendedElement` methods will never be called.

To get around this you need to store pointers to `Element` objects in your vector. A pointer to an `Element` can point to an actual `ExtendedElement` object and using virtual functions ensures that the correct function for the actual type will be called.